# Django, получение обьекта из DB, AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, django

Моя цель, получить объект из базы данных и отправить его как ответ используя AJAX , сам запрос работает нормально, проверил, проблема заключается в том что я не могу внутри функции обратится к модели и получить объект по id, ошибка Class 'CardItem' has no 'objects' member,  нашел пример в документации, пример кончено не совсем удачный, но он частично содержит то что мне нужно.

код из док.

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls.models import Poll

def detail(request, poll_id):
    try:
        p = Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id) # нужная мне строка
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Poll does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'poll': p})
```

Poll.objects.get(pk=poll_id) меня интересует именно эта строка, как сделать так же в моем примере

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from card.models import CardItem
import json
import datetime

# Create your views here.
class CardView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "card.html"    

def CardsGet(request):
        cards = CardItem.objects.get(id=2)
        html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % cards
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

В целом логика у меня получается такая, что из файла js я отправляю запрост на сервер по определенному адресу, который как раз  внутри view ссылается на ф-ю CardsGet, которая должна мне в формате json отправить данный из таблицы.
Пока конечно я не преобразую в json, мне нужно именно понять что все работает и я могу передать хотя бы строку в которой содержится объект.

У меня возникает ошибка Class 'CardItem' has no 'objects' member
в Django полный новичок, помогите кто чем может)

Comment: А Вы уверены, что ошибка возникает? Может ли это быть просто предупреждение линтера, который не умеет работать с `Django`? В `Python` нет ошибок такого вида. Сама конструкция для получения записи по `id` у Вас верна. Какую `IDE` Вы используете?

Comment: Использую Visual Studio Code, спасибо огромное за подсказку, все действительно работает, весь день сижу c Django и уже привычка выработалась что если вишу красную ошибку, где то косяк) к предупреждениям больше привык другого цвета.

Comment: Обратите внимание на этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47343542/11558617

Comment: Спасибо огромное за наводку

Answer (score 3):

Решение проблемы оказалось очень быстрым, для того что бы не было проблем при использовании VSC нужно

1) установить pylint-django https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django
причем если вы работает из под virtualenv установить надо именно там же, ну по крайне мере у меня сработало именно так.

2)Нужно добраться до настроек settings.json
   Зажмите комбинацию Ctrl+shift+p в появившемся окне ввести Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings далее выбрать язык python

3)"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins", "pylint_django"], вставить эту строчку в самый конец 
у меня получилось вот так

И ураа ошибки не стало)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Прошу прощения за беспокойство, все кто прочитал, в общем все работало. Сам виноват так сказать) Использую Visual Studio Code и по неопытности не правильно понял подсказку редактора.

Comment: Не стоит извиняться :) Лучше найдите и приведите решение, которое поможет избавиться от ложного предупреждения. Я оставил в комментариях ссылку, но не могу её проверить, так как не пользуюсь `Visual Studio Code`.